# Is there any rules for choosing letters about $a,b, c$ and $t$, or $2t$

Tags: terminology, education

---

we know：ellipse is the locus of dynamic point whose distances from two fixed points’ sum is fixed value.

so I write: $z$ is complex number, and $a,b,c,t$ are reals.

$$\begin{align*}\left| z-a\right| +\left| z-b\right| =c\tag{1}\end{align*}$$

Is there any guidelines/rules for choosing the $t$ and $c$? or $2t$? $2$ maybe related with focal length sometimes.

$$\begin{align*}\left| z-a\right| +\left| z-b\right| =t\tag{2}\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}\left| z-a\right| +\left| z-b\right| =2t\tag{3}\end{align*}$$

Comment: As long as your notations are not confusing, the choice of names of variables doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice between using a variable (such as $t$)
or that variable multiplied by a constant
(such as $2t$)
usually depends on the expressions that occur
later on in the computation.

For example,
if you started with $t$,
and $t/2$ occurred many times later on,
you might prefer to start with $2t$
so that $t$ would occur many times.

Another example is Fourier integrals,
where you can 
take the integral
from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ 
and the $\sin$ and $\cos$
of $x$
or
take the integral
from $-1$ to $1$ 
and the $\sin$ and $\cos$
of $\pi x$.

Another example:
when working out a
$\delta-\epsilon$ proof,
many books starta proof something like this:
"Let $\epsilon = \delta/4$."
After some computations,
the result comes out
"$|...| < \epsilon$."
They seem unwilling to start out with $\epsilon$
and end with a bound of,
say $4 \epsilon$.
I disapprove of this,
since, in my opinion,
introducing magic constants
distracts from the following of the proof
by the reader, especially the inexperienced reader.